# Reading object property value in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, node-mysql

I am trying to read the username property of the following JavaScript object and store it inside a variable.

```
[ RowDataPacket { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' } ]
```

It is being returned as a result object from an SQL query to a user database.
The returned object is called `result`
However, when I try to access its properties with

```
var sqlusername = result.username
```

or

```
var sqlusername = result.RowDataPacket.username
```

or

```
var sqlusername = result["username"]
```

or any other way to access the property,

the value of the variable var is always undefined.

How do I use the username and password properties of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is an array with one object in it. Use this:

```
result[0].username
```

Comment: Worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Destructure the given result as

```
const [{ username, password }] = result;
```